# Starting SQL querys from PHP script

Tags: php, mysql

I made a php script that starts sql queries from txt file. But cant figure out why it cant see queries inside txt file.

PHP:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = 'password';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully!';
$txt = file_get_contents('sql_query.txt');
$queries = explode(';', $txt);
foreach($queries as $sql){
   mysql_query($sql);
}
mysql_select_db('db');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not complete query - error!!!' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Success!!!\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Error is "Could not complete query - error!!!Query was empty".
sql_query.txt file contains queries like UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE...; INSERT INTO ...; etc.

Comment: where is te file name inside of `file_get_contents` ?

Comment: why when people start learning, they just prefer to go to tutorials million years old and have all deprecated functions in them, besides all they do is to teach you how to do bad coding!?

Comment: What is content of `$txt`?

Comment: For what you're doing, you don't need php for this.  You could do this using `mysql -u user -p password dbname < file_to_import.txt`.

Comment: Sorry, i fixed code now, somehow text got lost when typed.

Comment: isnt mysql_connect deprecated in favor of Mysqli or PDO_Mysql ?

Comment: If i change $txt code to $query_file = 'sql_query.txt';
$fp    = fopen($query_file, 'r');
$sql = fread($fp, filesize($query_file));
fclose($fp); then it tooks only one row from sql_query.txt but i need it to do more then one.

Comment: May I ask why are you loading the SQL statements from a text file?

Comment: I have about 1000 lines of sql queries and i think its easier to make one little php script then make all lines of queries to php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider dropping down to command line for this:

```
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = 'password';
$sql_file = '/path/to/sql_query.txt';
$command = escapeshellcmd('mysql -u ' . $dbuser . ' -p' . $dbpass . ' < ' . $sql_file);
echo exec($command);
```

Alternately, if you do decided to utilize `mysqli` instead of `mysql` (as others have noted you SHOULD do), you can utilize multi_query functionality.

```
$dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = 'password';
$sql_file = '/path/to/sql_query.txt';
// instantiate mysqli object
$db = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if($db->connect_error) {
    die('MySQL connection failed with: ' . $db->connect_error);
}
$sql = trim(file_get_contents($sql_file));
// execute query
if ($result = $db->multi_query($sql)) {
    do {
        // do something with each query result if needed
        $query_result = $db->store_result();
    } while ($db->next_result());
} else {
    die('Query failed with: ' . $db->error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at where the error is occurring: right after

```
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
```

Backtracking from there, what is the value of `$sql`? Well, you haven't set it since you exited the loop, so it's whatever the last value of the array is.

Now I haven't see what's in your text file, but I'm guessing it ends with a newline after the last query - something like:

```
SELECT * FROM foo;\n
SELECT * FROM bar;\n
```

If that's the case, it's likely that the last value of `$sql` is "\n", which is clearly not an SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of issues here. You have a call to `mysql_query` outside of your foreach loop... that doesn't seem right.

What's happening here is at the end of your `foreach`, the variable `$sql` is still set. You're only actually checking the return value after the loop, so actually your file is probably fine, although you seem to have a `;` character at the end of it followed by no query. This makes your final element of `$queries` an empty string.

You need to move your check inside your loop, like this:

```
foreach($queries as $sql){
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $retval ) {
        die('Could not complete query - error!!!' . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Take heed of the comments though - `mysql_query` etc is very outdated.

Comment: Tnx! This works and queries are processed but still gives error that query is empty not successful. :)